# AngularJS directive conditionally based on controller variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to display an error message about invalid login credentials whenever the user tries to logs in through non-matching username and password combination (through a request to the server, which returns the status for invalid login details in that case). I have created a directive for the same:

```
app.directive('invalid', function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function link(scope, element) {
            element.bind('submit', function (){
                var text = '<div class="uk-alert uk-alert-danger" ng-if="invalidCredentials"><p>Invalid username or password</p></div>';
                el = $compile( text )( scope );
                element.append(el);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

(notice the `ng-if` on the appended element)
I have applied this directive to the `form` element in the following manner:
`<form invalid name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginUser(loginDetails);" novalidate>`

Whenever the user credentials are invalid (checked through a request made to the server), the variable `$scope.invalidCredentials` is set to `true` (inside global controller).

It's working fine except for the fact that the directive triggers each time that the form is submitted. [No matter what the value of `$scope.invalidCredentials`]. `ng-if` doesn't seem to work.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: This directive seems redundant. Why not create a hidden div and display that according to your `$scope.invalidCredentials` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `element.bind('submit', function () { ... }` so the function will be called every time the form is submitted.

In the function we compile and append the HTML as is, **regardless** of the `ng-if` in it.
What you want to do is forego the directive like @omri said, and put the HTML code in the form, like so:

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginUser(loginDetails);" novalidate>
    ...
    <div class="uk-alert uk-alert-danger" ng-if="invalidCredentials">
        <p>Invalid username or password</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now the `<div>` will show whenever `invalidCredentials` is true.

*Note:*
Use directives when you have DOM manipulation on an element, or when an element comes up multiple times in your code. In your example I assume we will use this section only once(on your login page) so there is no need for the directive.

Comment: I created a hidden div and displayed it according to the value of `invalidCredentails`. But even then `ng-if` didn't seem to work. (`ng-show` worked for me though!).??

Comment: What version of angular are you using?
Also could you provide the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this instead?

```
       element.bind('submit', function (){
           if(scope.invalidCredentials){
            var text = '<div class="uk-alert uk-alert-danger"><p>Invalid username or password</p></div>';
            el = $compile( text )( scope );
            element.append(el);
           }
        });
```